# JS : Difference between Object and Object.constructor

Tags: javascript, prototype, ecmascript-5

I don't understand the difference between Object and Object.constructor.

Let's take an example :

```
function Person() {}
var p = new Person();
```

Person is the function to create objects. So :

```
p instanceof Person //true
p.constructor // Person
```

Person is the constructor and I can create persons with new Person()

But Object is also a constructor ( I can create object with new Object()). So why Object has a constructor property since it's already a constructor itself ?

Thanks

Comment: No the constructor has no constructor property, the instance constructed with the constructor has (inherits it from the prototype)

Comment: The Object() function does have a constructor property. But I don't know what it means

Comment: @JonasW. `Person.constructor` is inherited from `Function.prototype` as it is for all (constructor or not) functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So why does it have a constructor property since it's already a constructor itself?

Because every constructor is a function, and those inherit their properties (like the `call`, `apply` and `bind` methods) from [`Function.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype). Including the `Function.prototype.constructor` property, which points to `Function`.

Answer (score -1):

`constructor` is a pointer towards the `constructor function` used to create a given value, all objects have one. For primitives it points towards the primitive constructor: `Object`, `Number`, `Function` and so on.

Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor